# Multiple orWheres wont working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

hi guys i tried multiple wheres the 2 where is for filtering and the 2 other is for searching but when i add these 2 orwheres the first two where wont work but the last two is working i dont know whats the problem pls help me

I tried this code but its not working maybe i dont know how to use it

```
$estudiantes= Usuario::
        where('rol', '=', 'ESTUDIANTE')
            ->whereHas('perfil', function($query) use ($data){
                if($data!="")
                    $query->Where('doc_identidad', '=' ,$data)
                        ->orWhere('nombres','like','%'.$data.'%')
                        ->orWhere('apellidos','like','%'.$data.'%');
                dd($query);
            })->get();
```

this is my IndicatorController

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Indicator;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class IndicatorsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (request()->has('fin') OR request()->has('strat') OR request()->has('s')) {
            $joinindicators = DB::table('indicators')
                ->join('financial_categories', 'financial_categories.id', '=', 'indicators.financial_id')
                ->join('strategy_categories', 'strategy_categories.id', '=', 'indicators.strat_id')
                ->join('time_frame_categories', 'time_frame_categories.id', '=', 'indicators.timeframe_id')
                ->select('indicators.*', 'financial_categories.financial_type', 'strategy_categories.strategy',
                    'time_frame_categories.timeframe')
                ->where('financial_id', '=', request('fin'))->orwhere('strat_id', '=', request('strat'))
                ->orwhere('indicator_name', 'like', '%'.request('s').'%')
                ->orWhere('Description', 'like', '%'.request('s').'%')
                ->paginate(8)->appends([
                    'financial_id' => request('fin'),
                    'strat_id' => request('strat'),
                    //    'indicator_name' => request('s')
                ]);
        } else {

            $joinindicators = DB::table('indicators')
                ->join('financial_categories', 'financial_categories.id', '=', 'indicators.financial_id')
                ->join('strategy_categories', 'strategy_categories.id', '=', 'indicators.strat_id')
                ->join('time_frame_categories', 'time_frame_categories.id', '=', 'indicators.timeframe_id')
                ->select('indicators.*', 'financial_categories.financial_type', 'strategy_categories.strategy',
                    'time_frame_categories.timeframe')
                ->paginate(8);
        };

        $indis = Indicator::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(8);

        return view('pages.index_indicator', compact('joinindicators', 'indis'));
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put your "where" in lowercase.

```
$query->where
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: ->where('financial_id', '=',request('fin'))->orwhere('strat_id', '=',request('strat'))
        

these two where seems working but when i add the two  ->orwhere('indicator_name', 'like','%' .request('s'). '%')
      ->orwhere('Description', 'like','%' .request('s'). '%')

the first one wont work but the last two wheres work

Comment: @CalvinCalvento what do you mean when you say "won't work"? An expected ignored value is added?

Comment: instead of it filters when i choose a product it just shows all but the  like wheres is working